# this->geometry and other size functions returning windowsize and not widget size. - Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a widget (which inherits QWidget) that when the user clicks on it, he can drag it anywhere on the screen. I've implemented the mouseMoveEvent() and setMouseTracking() false for this widget. This is the code,

```
void Piece::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->buttons() == Qt::LeftButton && this->geometry().contains(event->pos()))
    {
    x = event->x()-18;
    y = event->y()-18;
    update();
    }
}
```

The problem is (after using the debugger) I find that geometry() gives the dimensions of the window (400x400) and not the widget dimensions (36x36). I've also tried other functions that returned QRects, and I've tried the underMouse() function, but every rect is 400x400 and the underMouse() function always returns true, even if the mouse isn't above the widget's image.

I have an idea of what the problem might be, which may be wrong. The application contains a checkerboard of squares, which each square being an object in part of a QGridLayout. In order to draw a widget on this grid (the playing piece), I just did,

```
layout->addWidget(pawn[0], 1, 1, 8, 8);
```

So in other words, the widget can be placed anywhere on the screen (the grid contains 8 rows and columns). If this is the problem, how do I display this piece widget on top of the grid layout? I've tried simply adding the widget to the parent widget, the same parent widget that is the parent to the QGridLayout (and I made sure to set the parent in the constructor), but that didn't work. If this is causing the problem, than how do I fix it? If not, what's causing the problem?

Comment: why not emit a signal when a Piece widget is clicked and handle it in the parent window (i.e. move the Piece widget in the parent window)?

Comment: @blueskin: Piece inherits QWidget and does not have it's own clicked signal. As far as I know, the only way to tell if it's clicked is to do it the way I tried, seeing if the mouse is over the widget when it's clicked. And if I try to see if the mouse is over the widget, it always says it is, because for some reason it believes the widget is the size of the entire window.

Comment: It's called mousePressEvent http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#mousePressEvent. There's also a double click event. And tracking mouse events is generally very expensive than just capturing events.

Comment: Why did you put 8 for the row and column span in addWidget ? It should be 1 (or omitted since this is the default).

Comment: @blueskin: I know, I've tried that. What I was saying in my first comment is that any mousePress anywhere on the screen (even if it's not on the widget) comes up as a mousePress on the widget. That's pretty much the problem stated in the question, that the bounds of the widget are appearing as the window size.

Comment: @alexisdm: I don't want that widget to a part of the grid. There are square objects that are a part of the grid and the Piece widgets can be placed anywhere on top of the grid, not necessarily in a row or column. I couldn't get them to display like that without adding them to the grid, but if I kept the span to be 1, they would only show up in a small portion of the window (the particular row and column they were added to). The way I did it allows them to be moved around the screen, but I also believe this method is causing the problem.

Comment: So all your widgets are really 400x400 but you only paint a 36x36 square. Maybe you should use a `QGraphicsScene` instead of a `QGridLayout`.

Comment: I switched to QGraphicsScene, which didn't help at all, but an inadvertent side effect of it (nontransparent backgrounds) made me realize that I could shrink the widget size to 36x36 (which made the widget disappear before) and then I could reposition the pixmap image to the visible area (before, the widget was shrunk but the pixmap was no in those bounds). So while your solution didn't really help directly, it helped indirectly. But in the end, QGraphicsView is a better choice than QGridLayout anyway.